# Managed property for changes on site?

Tags: search, publishing-site, display-template, managed-property, collaboration

In SharePoint 2013 on-prem I am using display templates to list out sites. I need to show the sites that have had any kind of updates lately.

I am looking for a property, that is a date and time stamp, which is updated each time anything inside a site changes.

Is there any such magical property?

Comment: LastContentModifiedDate or LastItemModifiedDate?

Comment: Hi Eric. I could find no such properties. Where do you find them ?

Comment: In the search configuration of central administration (in SPO), and I also see them as properties in powershell

Answer (score 1):

to find the recently visited sites, to find top sites etc. We can find it easily by using `site.LastItemModifiedDate.`

```
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("siteurl"))
            {
                SPWebCollection sites = siteCollection.AllWebs;
                foreach (SPWeb site in sites)
                {
                    DateTime dt = site.RegionalSettings.TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime(site.LastItemModifiedDate);
                    Console.WriteLine("site::::{0} Modified time::::{1}", site.Title, dt.ToString());

                }
            }
```

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Find-The-Last-Modified-Date-Of-A-SharePoint-Site-Programmatically-1745.php

or

This PowerShell script is intended to get the "LastModifiedDate" property (amongst others) of all sites in your SharePoint farm.The gathered informations are exported to a csv file, and optionally sent by email with the report as attachment.This script can be useful when auditing
 [SharePoint 2007/2010/2013 Sites: Export the 'Last Modified Date' Property](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-200720102013-48c9e2b1#content)

Comment: Thank you very much Waqas. I was hoping to use display templates and search only, but this is also very handy.